# Pentadactyl - disable Emacs-like (Ctrl) key mappings

Tags: vimperator, pentadactyl

I'm using Pentadactyl 1.0b7.2 and I'd like to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[key]</kbd> mappings.  I already mapped the actions I use the most to single key press. I also successfully remapped most of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[key]</kbd> mappings to their original actions, but some don't work correctly (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>).

Is there any way to completely disable all Pentadactyl's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[key]</kbd> mappings?